# Update all (local) affected forked branches when base commit was modified

Tags: git

Support I have git state as follows (letters in [] correspond to commit hash):

```
base[111] => branch_1[112], adds 1 commit => branch_2[113], adds 1 more commit
       \\
        \\=> branch_3[114], adds 1 totally different commit
```

Now I have to update `base` (fix critical review comment), so its commit hash changes from `111` to `222`. All forks (created with `git checkout -b`) won't be up to date, and that's what I want to fix. There are several approaches how to do that manually for example, rebasing or `git checkout base && git branch -D branch_1 && git checkout -b branch_1 && git cherry-pick 112`, repeat for all (local) affected children. Seems possible to automate this idea, but before proceeding I'd like to check if there's anything already available.

So, that's the question: is there any built-in functionality which would allow me to achieve desired goal?

Answer (score 1):

While on a branch, you can `git rebase base` to basically do what you've written out: switch to the new `base` and re-apply every commit from the branch you were on on top of the new `base`.

But since Git is decentralized, there is no way to loop this over "every" branch, since you don't know what branches may exist on other clones of the repo. If you know which branches you want to update, you can wrap the rebase in a simple bash loop:

```sh
for branch_name in branch1 branch2; do
    git rebase base ${branch_name}
done
```

Comment: Well, "every" means "every local"

Comment: Resulting script might be a bit more complex (branch2 should be rebased on the top of branch_1, after branch_1 is rebased on updated base). Plus there could be quirks if some sub-branches share commits.